# How to add Sonarqube into Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have installed sonar and jenkins. Now I want to add Sonarqube into Jenkins. But in the manage plugins, it doesn't show me the Sonarqube.[the display I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ogUb.png)

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube is a standalone server. It offers a web user interface to visualize bugs, code smells and vulnerabilities. You cannot include this web-ui SonarQube in Jenkins.

However, you can trigger a scan as part of your Jenkins job. This scan can "send" its findings into a SonarQube installation - either hosted by your own (on-premise), or using the hosting offer at sonarcloud.io.

There are a couple of different ways to include the scanner in your job, but the setup is specific to your programming language and build tools (Maven, VisualStudio, command line, ...). Check the [sonarcloud docs](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/) for the way, that fit's best to your situation.